# Tags: fakeroot and fakeroot-ng, should the latter be a synonym?

Tags: discussion

I just created three tags, whereas two ([fakeroot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fakeroot) and [fakeroot-ng](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fakeroot-ng)) are closely related. Regarding functionality the latter is a replacement for the former, but the innards are different.

Should the latter rather be a synonym?

If so, may I ask readers with enough rep to kindly suggest that synonym on my behalf? I tried and I am unable as of now.

Answer (score 1):

It is not so easy.

> Users with more than 2500 reputation and a **total answer score of 5 or
>   more on the tag**, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer
>   score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag,
>   can vote for tag synonyms. **Suggestions will be automatically approved
>   when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they
>   reach a score of -2**.

So if you have just created this tag nobody can suggest tag synonym, and even if someone could you still would need 4 other guys (each with 5 score on this tag) to approve the suggestion.

Perhaps moderators can help you...

Comment: You should probably point out that posting on meta is an entirely reasonable way to ask the moderators for help in things like this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to merge the two tags...

As you say, they're related in that they aim to accomplish the same goal. But the implementations are entirely different, and so are the behaviors. To quote the fakeroot-ng homepage:

> On the functional level, there are many differences between fakeroot and fakeroot-ng. Some of these differences are a result of the different technologies used by the two programs, and some are more derivatives of the above. The differences cover such areas as default ownership of unknown files, handling of SUID executables and chroot support. The differences are covered in more depth in the fakeroot vs fakeroot-ng comparison page.

Presumably, then, the questions could be distinct as well, and the experts as well.

Two separate tags seem entirely appropriate. Well, at least as well as can be determined from the 0 questions that actually are so tagged.

Comment: One is tagged [tag:fakeroot], none [tag:fakeroot-ng] as I was unsure. Thanks for the answer.